# Regession on variables when comparing to a baseline

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation

Consider an experiment where apples are being grown. Some trees may tend to naturally grow more apples (say, for example, because some are located in places that have more sun or water). There are three distinct periods in this experiment. A "baseline period" where no fertilizer is applied. A "fertilizer period" period where fertilizer is applied. And a "after-effect period" where fertilizer has been removed.

- $x_i$ = number of new apples that grow on the $i$th tree during the baseline period.
- $y_i$ = number of new apples that grow on the $i$th tree during the fertilizer period
- $z_i$ = number of new apples that grow on the $i$th tree during the after-effect period

I would like to answer the question: "How does the **change** in the number of apples grown during the fertilizer period (relative to the baseline period) influence the **change** in the number of apples grown during the after-effect period (also relative to the baseline period)."

To summarize, we have three different random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ under different conditions and possibly dependent on each other through time. Because we are **only interested changes caused by the different conditions**, we subtract the baseline ($X$) from both $Y$ and $Z$ to get the relative change. In our experiment above, this controls for some tree naturally producing more apples.

We would answer this question by regressing $\Delta Y = Y - X$  versus $\Delta Z = Z - X$. However, this would give a correlation even if $Y$ and $Z$ were completely independent. In our example, even if the fertilizer did nothing, our regression would say that an improvement in apple growing during the fertilizer period (ie $\Delta Y$) lead to an improvement in apple growing during the after-effect period ($\Delta Z$). This is because we are subtracting $X$ from both terms.

Alternatively, if we just regressed $Y$ versus $Z$, then we may get a spurious correlation because some trees may naturally produce more apples.

---

1) Is there a way to properly handle this scenario with regression? What would be the correct hypothesis test to perform if plotting $\Delta Y$ versus $\Delta Z$? Is there a way to correct for the baseline subtraction?

2) What would be the correct way to perform a permutation test? If we regress $\Delta Y$ versus $\Delta Z$ how would we switch the period labels? Would we only permute the labels for the baseline and growing periods? or would we permute the labels for all 3 periods?

(Don't let the fact that trees can't grow a fraction of an apple or a negative number of apples influence your answer. I only gave that example for intuition. It's also possible that zero apples grow during our baseline period.)

Comment: I personally would regress the first change,  Y-X, versus the second change Z-Y.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why this would be better?

Comment: My purpose would be to have a better understanding of both the problem and the available data, rather than to have a definitive answer that is better. I would want to know to what degree these two things are related.